# Make install new Python minor release over previous one

Tags: python, installation

I have built and installed Python 2.7.8 from source on CentOS 6 with the following commands:

```
./configure --prefix /opt/Python27 --exec-prefix=/opt/Python27
make
make install
```

Now 2.7.9 is out and I would like to update my installation. Is it reasonable to expect everything to keep working if I uncompress it in a different directory from the previous one and install it with exactly the same commands, i.e. over the previous installation?

Comment: Is there a reason you _want_ to do this? Unless you need any of the [New Features Added to Python 2.7 Maintenance Releases](https://docs.python.org/2.7/whatsnew/2.7.html#new-features-added-to-python-2-7-maintenance-releases), or a particular bug fix from the tracker, it's unlikely to buy you anything.

Comment: Come to think of it, for deployment to a lot of systems, [PEP 453](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0453)/[PEP 477](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0477) might be a good enough reason, as a good way to make sure they all start with a working `pip`…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, you're *probably* OK, and the worst-case scenario isn't that bad.

I'm not sure if Python 2.x ever guaranteed binary-API stability between micro versions.* But, according to [the dev guide](https://docs.python.org/devguide/devcycle.html#maintenance-branches):

> The only changes allowed to occur in a maintenance branch without debate are bug fixes. Also, a general rule for maintenance branches is that compatibility must not be broken at any point between sibling minor releases (3.4.1, 3.4.2, etc.). For both rules, only rare exceptions are accepted and must be discussed first.

So, in theory, there could have been a compatibility-breaking release between 2.7.8 and 2.7.9, and the only way to know for sure is to dig through the bug tracker and the python-dev mailing list and so on to see where it was discussed and accepted. And of course they could always have screwed up and make a breaking change without realizing it. But in practice, the first has only happened a few times in history, and the second has as far as I know never happened.

Another thing that can cause a problem is major changes to the required or optional dependencies that Python builds against between your last build. But this is pretty rare in practice. If you've, say, uninstalled `zlib` since the last build, then yeah, that could break compatibility, but you're unlikely to have done anything like that.

So, what happens if either of those is true? It just means that any binary extensions, or embedding apps, that you've built need to be rebuilt.

Hopefully you've been using `pip`, in which case, if there's a problem, getting a list of all the extensions in your site-packages and force-reinstalling them is trivial (although it may take a while to run). And if you're using a lot of virtual environments, you could need to do the same for all of them. As for embedding, if you don't know about it, you're not doing it (unless you've built "semi-standalone" executables with something like pyInstaller, which I doubt you have).

So, not too terrible. And, remember, that's usually not a problem at all, it's just the worst-case scenario.